# How to use Mac Launcher and OAuth2 with stored credentials?

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm using GoogleAppEngineLauncher 1.9.18 from the Google App Engine SDK for Python on Mac (OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite).

OAuth2 through the browser is now [the only way to deploy with the Mac Launcher.](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.9.18_-_February_19,_2015)

When I deploy my app, the console outputs:

```
*** Running appcfg.py with the following flags:
     --no_cookies --oauth2 update
```

But I do want my OAuth2 credentials to be stored. And because of the --no_cookies flag, appcfg.py will not store my credentials in ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens. So every time I deploy my app my browser will open to the Google Account OAuth2 page so I allow appcfg to manage my apps.

I ran manually:

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 update myapp/
```

And it created the ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens file after I did the OAuth2. Now each time I run manually appcfg.py with OAuth2 it works without opening the browser.

But with the Mac Launcher, appcfg.py ignores the .appcfg_oauth2_tokens file because of the --no_cookies flag.

How can I force the Mac Launcher not to use the --no_cookies flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have premium Google App Engine support and contacted them regarding this same issue. Google told me that this is a known issue which they are tracking internally, under internal ticket #19324800.

They estimate the fix will be ready by version 1.9.19, but it is possible it could slip to release 1.9.20.

Comment: Thank you A LOT for contacting them and confirming it's a known issue!